# Why is a string literal copied when assigning to a const std::string?

Tags: c++, string, optimization, copy, string-literals

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), when a `const std::string` is constructed from an input `const char*` (e.g. `const std::string("some literal");`), a *copy* of the C string is stored in the `std::string`.

I'm trying to understand if (and why) the copy is required specifically in the case where the input C string is a string literal.  I would think that the `std::string` could simply refer to the string literal instead of creating a copy, so that the following code would only create `"some literal"` once.

```
std::string str1("some literal");
std::string str2("some literal");
```

Certainly, performing a copy for C strings that aren't string literals is wise, because it allows the `std::string` to manage the lifetime of the data that it refers to.  However, this is not an issue for string literals because they exist for the lifetime of the program.

Also, since we are talking about `const` strings, we don't need to worry about the underlying data being changed during the program and breaking the value semantics of the `std::string`s.  Well, at least as long as `const_cast` isn't used, but using `const_cast` is asking for trouble anyway, so I'm not too worried about that case.

So, is there any reason why the compiler can't optimize this case to have `const std::string`s refer to `const char*`s instead of creating copies?  Alternatively, if the cppreference link was incorrect, and this optimization actually *is* implemented by some compilers, which compilers support this?

For the sake of this question, let's assume that the string literal is long enough that the small string optimization won't be a factor.

Comment: Allowing a `std::string` to store a string literal would mean another piece of information and logic to know whether the string needs to deallocate the memory it holds on destruction. Take a look at `std::string_view`.

Comment: @tkausl that sounds pretty close to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, a `std::string` simply receives a pointer, it has no way of know what kind of memory that pointer is actually pointing at.

The fact that the pointer is declared as pointing to const data is not relevant.  A pointer to non-const data can be assigned to a pointer to const data (creating read-only access to otherwise writable data).

The `std::string` simply has no way of knowing that the pointer it is given is pointing at a string literal. The pointer could just as easily be pointing at an array on the call stack, or to a memory block allocated with `new`, or to memory owned by an external library.

There is nothing special about a narrow string literal, it is not some magic type that `std::string` could adjust its behavior for.  It is just a plain ordinary `const char[]`, just one whose memory is setup by the compiler/linker.  It decays to `const char *`.

So `std::string` does the only sane and safe thing it can do given the lack of origin info - make a copy of the data.

That also keeps the implementation simple - the `std::string` always owns the data it holds.

If you want a string-like container that doesn't own the data, just points at it, then look at C++17's [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), or [`boost::string view`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/utility/string_view.hpp) for earlier compilers.

Comment: That's fair. I was thinking that since the compiler knows that the input is a string literal, it might be capable of controlling the behavior. But I hadn't really thought through how this would be achieved.

Comment: On top of this if the literal string is coming from an external dylib, the memory for the literal will tend to be unloaded when the library is unloaded even though the application is still running, and we run into UB. Further a class doesn't necessarily know it's going to be constructed as a read-only object, so to speak, so there's not a way to special case in the constructor of `std::string` when it is going to be instantiated as a const object. That tends to require a separate class/type outright if you want it to be "aware" that it's only going to be used for read-only purposes in some ...

Comment: ... particular context including in its ctor, like `std::const_string`. In general it's much more practical to dedicate that `string_view` type, e.g., for such purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the standard string class, but if we consider the `QString` class of **the Qt Framework**, i.e.:

```
QString hello("Hello");
```

Assuming that the source code file you are using is encoded in **UTF-8**, the above `"Hello"` string literal is going to be stored as an array of 8-bit numbers on your hard drive. On the other hand, the `QString` class stores actual string data in memory by dividing each character into `QChar` objects, which in return stores each character in 16-bit **UTF-16** encoded numbers when the app is running after the compilation. Meaning that the `QString` class must translate the string data in **UTF-8** (source encoding format) to **UTF-16** (its internal encoding format) right when initializing the string object. Thus requires a larger memory area than the original text data to hold the string in memory, so it makes an internal copy of the data for its own specific usage. Similarly, inner workings of the standard strings might be the problem here.